# React Router reset state on every route change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have defined routes and for all those routes I have defined a fixed top navbar component to be there always no matter what route is rendering component, just like this 
[image] 
So I have links for those routes in topnavbar and when user clicks on a link it changes the route and tonavbar losses its state how can i keep state of topnavbar when route changes ?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or links to images, as images are not searchable and this makes it hard to understand your question once the image target gets removed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images for more information.